# My while loop never reaches the conditional stament and keeps looping

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-statements

The assignment was to make a guessing game where the parameter is the answer. At the end if the person gets it right, it prints a congratulatory statement and returns the number of tries it took, if they type in quit, it displays the answer and tries == -1. other than that, it keeps looping until they get the answer correct.

```
def guessNumber(num):
    tries = 1
    while tries > 0:
        guess = input("What is your guess? ")
        if guess == num:
            print ("Correct! It took you" + str(tries)+ "tries. ")
            return tries
        elif guess == "quit":
            tries == -1
            print ("The correct answer was " + str(num) + ".")
            return tries
        else:
            tries += 1
```

When i run it, no matter what i put in it just keeps asking me for my guess.

Comment: `break` , then `return`

Comment: If it keeps asking after typing "quit", then you should analyse the part where you call this function. Do you call it in a loop?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the actual indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you called your variable `num` so  I'm guessing it's a integer, you were checking equality between an integer and a string so it's never True. Try changing the num to str(num) when comparing, so:

```
def guessNumber(num):
    tries = 1
    while tries > 0:
        guess = input("What is your guess? ")
        if guess == str(num):
            print ("Correct! It took you {0} tries. ".format(tries))
            return tries
        elif guess == "quit":
            tries = -1
            print ("The correct answer was {0}.".format(num))
            return tries
        else:
            tries += 1
```

Comment: That does fix the problem, but now i cant input "quit" because its not an integer.

Comment: I realized my mistake so I changed my answer 18 mins ago sorry for the confusion. @MalaikatuKargbo The code above should work. It works the same under the same principle.

Answer (score -1):

Is the code properly indented?
The body of the function you are defining is determined by the level of indentation.

In the example you pastes, as the line right after the def has less indentation, the body of the function is 'empty'.

[Indenting code is important in python](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html)

Additionally, for assigning one value to a variable you have to use a single '=', so the:

```
tries == -1
```

should be

```
tries = -1
```

if you want to assign the -1 value to that variable.

Comment: Definitely not the solution. Empty functions would result in a Exception.